# How to sample Image A with coordinates from image B, using compositing editor nodes?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I need an operation, mathematically written as

`ImgOut[x,y] = A[ B[x,y].red , B[x,y].green ]`

Is it possible to implement this with blender compositing editor nodes?

Comment: If the coords come from normals(?) you could decompose them via Converter nodes Seperate RGB?

Comment: @3pointedit They are actually already decomposed. How can this help?

Comment: Its not clear how you want to use the product as that may inform the type of nodes you need to use. If you want a mixed color result or a value result on seperate channels...